# Как установить пакет из tbz архива?

Tags: freebsd

Есть пакет **zip-3.0.tbz**. Пытаюсь его добавить

```
pkg add ./zip-3.0.tbz
```

Выводит ошибку

```
pkg: zip-3.0.tbz is not a valid package: no manifest found
Failed to install the following 1 package(s): zip-3.0.tbz
```

Как быть в таком случае? FreeBSD 11 щас стоит у меня.

Comment: pkg_add ./zip-3.0.tbz - так не пробовали? Сдаётся мне что pkg и pkg_add разные программы для немного разных целей

Comment: ставьте из портов и не мучайтесь, почему нет?

Comment: @AntonioK Можете на меня сердиться, но порты противные, мокрые и нет деревьев. Двадцать первый век на дворе, а вы всё со своими портами. Собирательство из портов - это не для нормальных людей. Это тупо долго. Дольше чем копирование готового бинарника. Требует поддержки (инфра?)структуры для сборки портов на весь зоопарк шелезяк. Все это чего-то стоит, времени, денег, нервов. В качестве хобби - пожалуйста. Но для дела - лишние издержки.

Comment: @AntonioK Да и в мировом масштабе сами посудите - разве хорошо, когда мильёны компьютеров собирают один и тот же бинарник в течении полусуток, вместо того, чтобы работать на благо обчечеловеческого щастья? Пусть один из них компильнёт всё, а другие не отвлекаясь от своей задачи обновятся на перекуре за пару сек.

Comment: собирать пакет zip полсуток? Вы на часы "атланта" из 90-х годов фрю поставили? ставьте из пакетов и не мучайтесь, это РОДНОЙ способ установки ПО в ОС FreeBSD. для граничных случаев вроде libreoffice который, да, собирать придётся несколько часов, распространяются РОДНЫЕ прекомпилированные пекэджи для FreeBSD, с которыми проблем, вроде описанной Вами, не возникает. для всего остального есть gcc/clang/%compilername%

Answer (score 1):

> Как быть в таком случае? FreeBSD 11 щас стоит у меня.

Если внимательно присмотреться, то утилита кагбэ намекает "no manifest found". А это значит, наверное файла манифеста нет. Его вообще нет. Полностью.

Вывод? Нужен файл манифеста. Необходимо его взять там, где был взят архив. Если такой возможности нет - попробовать сгенерировать (написать) его самому. Для начала, думаю неплохо выкурить [этот ман](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?pkg-create(8)#end) (а именно раздел "MANIFEST FILE DETAILS"), поискать в сети примеры, таки сконструировать его, и скормить утилите pkg.

ЗЫ: Платные услуги по генерации файлов манифеста я, увы, еще ни разу не оказывал. У самого знания концептуальные. Но могу, практически уверен)